# Android emulator is not working in linux

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I have been developing an android game on my gentoo amd64 linux for some time using the eclipse IDE with an android device successfully. However, I need to test my game with different screen sizes to make sure it still displays correctly. In result, I decided to try the emulator.

After I set one up and type ./emulator -avd SamsungGalaxy in terminal, nothing happens, it just quits. adb logcat just continues to log - waiting for device -.

This is what I tried.

Waiting - I know the emulator can take quite some time to boot.

Reinstalling ADT and Android SDK

Restarting eclipse

Rebooting my machine

After lots of searching on google and this site, I am still stumped at the moment. Any ideas is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Trust me. You don't want to use the android emulators. Let alone use it to test a game. I would suggest finding a beta tester with that screen size.

Comment: Have you tried launching the emulator from eclipse?

Comment: Agreed, my previous experience with it was very lacking and buggy, especially on the opengles front. Frankly, I am not surprised it is not working right now. But I was hoping it could serve up to its name for my test. If I have to go find someone, it will come down to that, but I don't know anyone with a different screen size :( .

Comment: Yes, I tried launching the emulator from eclipse as well.

Comment: yes, the emulator emulates a whole device (it's based on [qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) afaik) including the processor (ARM unless you use those intel images) and the graphic chip, that's slow as hell compared to real devices that have actual hardware accelleration.

Answer (score 0):

Try killing the process that is running the adb  then restarting Eclipse and creating a new avd might help...

Comment: I got the same problem still after this. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these options to the command line

```
-no-audio                   disable audio support
-gpu off                    disable hardware OpenGLES emulation mode
```

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK is 32bit, therefore on a 64bit Linux system you need to have the package ia32-libs installed. For Ubuntu you can do this via the following command.

```
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Got from an [article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#installation_linux64)